# DJANGO > Accounts > INPUT "password" duplicado

Tags: python, django

Tengo una configuración para *account* o *sistema de registro de nuevos usuarios*. En el código indico los parámetros y clase para el estilo, pero no sé de dónde sale otro *input*. *En vez de 4 input, salen 5 input*. ¿Qué sucede?

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserCreationFormWithEmail(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text="Requerido, 254 caracteres como máximo y debe ser válido")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","email","password","password2")
```

views.py

```
from .forms import UserCreationFormWithEmail
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django import forms

# Create your views here.
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationFormWithEmail
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('login') + '?register'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(SignUpView, self).get_form()
        #Modificar en tiempo real
        form.fields['username'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-2','placeholder':'Nombre de usuario'})
        form.fields['email'].widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-2','placeholder':'Dirección email'})
        form.fields['password1'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-2','placeholder':'Contraseña'})
        form.fields['password2'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-2','placeholder':'Repite la contraseña'})
        return form
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import SignUpView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
]
```

Salida (*4 input en vez de 5 input*) Sobra el del medio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuales serian los 5 input? Yo veo que la user form tiene 4 campos y el template muestra 4, no entiendo cual sería el que falta.

Comment: Debajo de "Requerido, 254 caracteres como máximo y debe ser válido"... hay un input (un recuadro más pequeño que los demás). Eso es un input que no se de dónde sale. Es como si por defecto crea alguno, y aunque yo cree en views.py inputs, esos no se fueran. No lo se.

Comment: @julian muestra el signup.html

Comment: Solucionado, en forms.py en vez de password tenía que poner password1 y funciona perfecto. Si se pone password lo considera diferente y genera otro nuevo input de más.

Comment: Buenisimo, podrias incluso responder tu propia pregunta sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, en forms.py en vez de password hay que poner password1 y funciona perfecto. Si se pone password lo considera diferente y genera otro nuevo input de más.